# How to implement saving and loading json file in Fleatherfield?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, mobile

I have two textfield here labeled title and content. I just want to know how to implement the same kind of saving and loading of json file since the controller of the fleatherfield doesnt have the getter 'text' in saving the file.

Basically, I want the text saved from this flutter textfield, to this fleather textfield.

[image]

Here is my create_journal.dart.

```
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/theme/theme_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/models/journal_entry.dart';
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/services/ads.dart';
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/widgets/appbar.dart';
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/services/journal_data_manager.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fleather/fleather.dart';
import 'package:quill_delta/quill_delta.dart';

class CreateJournal extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateJournal({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateJournal> createState() => _CreateJournalState();
}

class _CreateJournalState extends State<CreateJournal> {
  late double _fontSize = 26.0;
  late JournalEntry journalEntry;
  late TextEditingController _titleController;
  late TextEditingController _textController; // I want this text controller to be a fleathercontroller

  late FleatherController _controller; // test fleather controller
  late FocusNode _focusNode;

  File ? _selectedImage;

  Future<void> saveEntry() async {
    await JournalDataManager.saveEntry(JournalEntry(
        dateTime: journalEntry.dateTime,
        title: _titleController.text,
        content: _textController.text, //save the entry to content from _controller however, I tried _controller.text, it responds to an error
        filePath: journalEntry.filePath
    ));
  }

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final returnedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); // You can also use ImageSource.camera

    setState(() {
      _selectedImage = File(returnedImage!.path);
    });
    /*
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      // Do something with the picked image file (e.g., update your FleatherField)
      // Example: _controller.insertEmbed(Embed.image(pickedFile.path));
    }
     */
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _titleController = TextEditingController();
    _textController = TextEditingController(); // REPLACE

    _controller = FleatherController();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleController.dispose();
    _textController.dispose(); // REPLACE

    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, dynamic>? arguments =
    ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>?;

    if (arguments?['journalEntry'] != null) {
      journalEntry = arguments!['journalEntry'];
      _titleController.text = journalEntry.title;
      _textController.text = journalEntry.content;
    } else {
      journalEntry = JournalEntry();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const ReliefAppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  // TITLE FIELD
                  TextField(
                    controller: _titleController,
                    maxLength: 24,
                    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                    maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      counterText: '',
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
                      hintText: 'Title',
                      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    ),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                  // JOURNAL FIELD

                  TextField(
                    controller: _textController,
                    maxLength: 1000,
                    maxLines: null,
                    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                    maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
                      hintText: 'How\'s your day?',
                      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    ),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: _fontSize,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  // Toolbar
                  Theme(
                    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                        disabledColor: Colors.red, //used for disabled icons
                        primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white70), //used for toggled icons
                        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54)), //used for not toggled icons
                    child: FleatherToolbar.basic(
                      controller: _controller,
                      hideDirection: true,
                      hideHorizontalRule: true,
                      hideLink: true,
                      hideQuote: true,
                      hideCodeBlock: true,
                      hideInlineCode: true,
                      hideIndentation: true,
                      hideHeadingStyle: true,
                      hideUndoRedo: true,
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Fleather Journal Field
                  FleatherField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
                      hintText: 'How\'s your day?',
                      hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    ),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 10),

                  _selectedImage != null ? Image.file(_selectedImage!) : const Text("Please select an image"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 80,),
          AdService.bannerAd
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 50,
            right: 0.0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'saveButton',
              onPressed: () async {
                await saveEntry();
                if (context.mounted) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.save_rounded),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 120,
            right: 0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'uploadButton',
              onPressed: () {
                _pickImage();
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.upload),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried following the example in the fleather documentation however, the example only shows to save into a temporary file.

Here is the journal_*data*_manager.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:com.relief.motivationalapp/models/journal_entry.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

class JournalDataManager {

  static Future<void> init() async {
    getJournalEntries();
  }

  static Future<String> generateEncryptionKey() async {
    const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    // generate and store secret key using the keystore system
    final random = Random.secure();
    final keyBytes = List<int>.generate(32, (index) => random.nextInt(256));
    final key = base64Encode(keyBytes);
    await secureStorage.write(key: 'encryption_key', value: key);
    return key;
  }

  static Future<String> retrieveEncryptionKey() async {
    const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    String key = await secureStorage.read(key: 'encryption_key') ?? await generateEncryptionKey();
    return key;
  }

  static Future<void> saveEntry(JournalEntry entry) async {

    String timeISOString = entry.dateTime!.toIso8601String();

    // get encryption key
    final String encryptionKey = await retrieveEncryptionKey();
    final Uint8List keyBytes = base64.decode(encryptionKey);

    // prepare data
    String jsonString = jsonEncode({
      'dateTime': timeISOString,
      'title': entry.title,
      'content': entry.content,
    });

    // encrypt data
    final IV iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final Encrypter encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key(keyBytes)));
    final Encrypted encryptedJson = encrypter.encrypt(jsonString, iv: iv);

    // generate filepath
    late final File file;
    late final String filePath;
    if (entry.filePath == null) {
      String fileName = 'journal_$timeISOString';

      // get the save directory
      Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String saveDir = File(p.join(appDir.path, 'journal_entries')).path;

      // create the save directory if it does not exist
      Directory directory = await Directory(saveDir).create(recursive: true);
      filePath = p.join(appDir.path, 'journal_entries', fileName);

      dev.log('created the directory: $directory');
    } else {
      filePath = entry.filePath!; // get the filePath from the JournalEntry
    }

    file = File(filePath);
    await file
        .writeAsBytes(encryptedJson.bytes)
        .then((_) => dev.log('Journal entry written to file: $filePath'))
        .catchError((error) => dev.log('Error writing to JSON file $error'));
  }

  static Future<String> loadEntry(String filePath) async {
    // get key
    final String key = await retrieveEncryptionKey();
    final keyBytes = base64.decode(key);

    // read file
    final File file = File(filePath);
    final Uint8List encryptedJson = await file.readAsBytes();

    // decrypt file
    final IV iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final Encrypter encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key(keyBytes)));
    final String decryptedJson = encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted(encryptedJson), iv: iv);

    return decryptedJson;
  }

  static Future<List<JournalEntry>> getJournalEntries() async {

    // get the save directory
    Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String journalDir = File(p.join(appDir.path, 'journal_entries')).path;
    Directory directory = Directory(journalDir);

    List<String> filePaths = [];

    if (directory.existsSync()) {
      List<FileSystemEntity> files = directory.listSync();
      files
          .sort((a, b) => a.statSync().changed.compareTo(b.statSync().changed));

      filePaths = files.whereType<File>().map((file) => file.path).toList();
    } else {
      dev.log('Journal directory not found');
    }

    List<JournalEntry> loadJournalEntries = [];
    for (String filePath in filePaths) {
      try {
        String jsonString = await loadEntry(filePath);

        Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonString);

        loadJournalEntries.add(JournalEntry(
            title: jsonData['title'],
            content: jsonData['content'],
            dateTime: DateTime.parse(jsonData['dateTime']),
            filePath: filePath
        ));
      } catch (e) {
        dev.log('Error reading JSON file: $e');
      }
    }

    // sort by dateTime
    loadJournalEntries.sort((JournalEntry a, JournalEntry b) {
      DateTime firstDateTime = a.dateTime as DateTime;
      DateTime secondDateTime = b.dateTime as DateTime;
      return secondDateTime.compareTo(firstDateTime);
    });

    return loadJournalEntries;
  }

  static Future<void> deleteEntry(String? filePath) async {
    if (filePath == null) {
      return;
    }

    File file = File(filePath);

    if (file.existsSync()) {
      file.deleteSync();
      dev.log('journal entry $filePath deleted.');
    } else {
      dev.log('journal entry $filePath does not exist.');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to save and load document is json encoding it. Using `controller.document.toDelta().toList()` you can retrieve your document as a list of operations and by encoding this list to json you can save it anywhere you want (Remote server, Local database, Firebase, ...). Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fleather/fleather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(const FleatherApp());

class FleatherApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FleatherApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
        title: 'Fleather - rich-text editor for Flutter',
        home: HomePage(),
      );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FleatherController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _load();
  }

  Future<void> _save(ParchmentDocument document) async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString(
        'document', json.encode(document.toDelta().toList()));
  }

  Future<void> _load() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ParchmentDocument? document;
    if (preferences.containsKey('document')) {
      document = ParchmentDocument.fromJson(
          json.decode(preferences.getString('document')!));
    }
    _controller = FleatherController(document: document);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0, title: Text('Fleather Demo')),
      floatingActionButton: _controller != null
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => _save(_controller!.document),
              child: Icon(Icons.save),
            )
          : null,
      body: _controller == null
          ? Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Column(
              children: [
                FleatherToolbar.basic(controller: _controller!),
                Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1, color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                Expanded(
                  child: FleatherEditor(
                    controller: _controller!,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 16,
                      right: 16,
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                    ),
                    maxContentWidth: 800,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The saving in the sharedpreferences works. However, I am trying to save it to a directory in a device that includes the title, content, datetime and filepath as shown in journal_data_manager.dart.

Comment: The code you've posted makes it a bit hard to pinpoint the problem but it should work with any other approach to save and retrieve the data. @ArielArevalo

Comment: Was able to finally make it work using ParchmentDocument.fromJson syntax and replacing _textController.text = journalEntry.content to document = ParchmentDocument.fromJson(json.decode(journalEntry.content));
      _controller = FleatherController(document: document); Thank you very much!